# I don't have data on my phone, can I still send and receive bitcoin without internet?

Tags: sending, receiving, offline-transactions

I dont have internet on my phone at all at the bitcoin ATM and want to know if i can still receive my bitcoin with my phone

Comment: Hi, in theory you can just provide an address and someone can broadcast a transaction that pays to this address even if right at this moment you're offline, but obviously you can't see an incoming transaction if you're not online. But I'm just making a very general statement here, I think you could provide more specific information, especially about the ATM and the software you're using in order to receive precise answers

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can receive Bitcoin even if you don't have internet, but you will only see them when you synchronize your wallet (for this you need internet).